# ¿Cómo se pueden enviar notificaciones desde una extension de chrome?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome

pues verán, estoy desarrollando una extensión de chrome y quisiera saber cómo se pueden enviar notificaciones desde la extensión, es decir notificaciones de escritorio

PD: Ya lo googleé y no me sale :c
no se si estoy buscando bien

Comment: Buscando en Google encontre [esta API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications), aunque está en inglés, no sé si te sirva.